# array object manipulation to create new object

Tags: javascript

```
var actual = [
 {"country":"UK","month":"JAN","SR":"John P","AC":"24","PR":"2","TR":1240},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"JAN","SR":"Brad    P","AC":"64","PR":"12","TR":1700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"JAN","SR":"Gim P","AC":"21","PR":"5","TR":900},

 {"country":"UK","month":"FEB","SR":"John P","AC":"14","PR":"4","TR":540},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"FEB","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":1700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"FEB","SR":"Gim P","AC":"22","PR":"3","TR":600},

 {"country":"UK","month":"MAR","SR":"John P","AC":"56","PR":"2","TR":1440},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"MAR","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"MAR","SR":"Gim P","AC":"51","PR":"5","TR":200}
 ];

var expect = [
{month:"JAN",val: {"UK":"24","AUSTRIA":"64","ITALY":"21"}},
{month:"FEB",val: {"UK":"14","AUSTRIA":"24","ITALY":"22"}},
{month:"MAR",val: {"UK":"56","AUSTRIA":"24","ITALY":"51"}}
];
```

I have array of objects which i need to reshape for one other work. need some manipulation which will convert by one function. I have created plunker https://jsbin.com/himawakaju/edit?html,js,console,output

Main factors are Month, Country and its "AC" value.

Comment: and your question is ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through, make an object and than loop through to make your array

```
var actual = [
 {"country":"UK","month":"JAN","SR":"John P","AC":"24","PR":"2","TR":1240},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"JAN","SR":"Brad    P","AC":"64","PR":"12","TR":1700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"JAN","SR":"Gim P","AC":"21","PR":"5","TR":900},

 {"country":"UK","month":"FEB","SR":"John P","AC":"14","PR":"4","TR":540},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"FEB","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":1700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"FEB","SR":"Gim P","AC":"22","PR":"3","TR":600},

 {"country":"UK","month":"MAR","SR":"John P","AC":"56","PR":"2","TR":1440},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"MAR","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"MAR","SR":"Gim P","AC":"51","PR":"5","TR":200}
 ];

var outTemp = {};
actual.forEach(function(obj){ //loop through array
    //see if we saw the month already, if not create it
    if(!outTemp[obj.month]) outTemp[obj.month] = { month : obj.month, val: {} };
    outTemp[obj.month].val[obj.country] = obj.AC;  //add the country with value
});
var expected = [];  //convert the object to the array format that was expected
for (var p in outTemp) {
    expected.push(outTemp[p]);
}
console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through array and create new list

```js
var actual = [
 {"country":"UK","month":"JAN","SR":"John P","AC":"24","PR":"2","TR":1240},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"JAN","SR":"Brad    P","AC":"64","PR":"12","TR":1700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"JAN","SR":"Gim P","AC":"21","PR":"5","TR":900},

 {"country":"UK","month":"FEB","SR":"John P","AC":"14","PR":"4","TR":540},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"FEB","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":1700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"FEB","SR":"Gim P","AC":"22","PR":"3","TR":600},

 {"country":"UK","month":"MAR","SR":"John P","AC":"56","PR":"2","TR":1440},
 {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"MAR","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":700},
 {"country":"ITALY","month":"MAR","SR":"Gim P","AC":"51","PR":"5","TR":200}
 ];

var newList =[], val;
for(var i=0; i < actual.length; i+=3){
   val = {};
   val[actual[i].country] = actual[i]["AC"];
  val[actual[i+1].country] = actual[i+1]["AC"];
  val[actual[i+2].country] = actual[i+2]["AC"];
   newList.push({month: actual[i].month, val:val})
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newList);
```

Comment: The solution is good if the order is always correct and there in no missing months/country for data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code... as above solution will help you if there are 3 rows and these will be in same sequnece.

Here is perfect solution :

```
   var actual = [
                         {"country":"UK","month":"JAN","SR":"John P","AC":"24","PR":"2","TR":1240},
                         {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"JAN","SR":"Brad    P","AC":"64","PR":"12","TR":1700},
                         {"country":"ITALY","month":"JAN","SR":"Gim P","AC":"21","PR":"5","TR":900},

                         {"country":"UK","month":"FEB","SR":"John P","AC":"14","PR":"4","TR":540},
                         {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"FEB","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":1700},
                         {"country":"ITALY","month":"FEB","SR":"Gim P","AC":"22","PR":"3","TR":600},

                         {"country":"UK","month":"MAR","SR":"John P","AC":"56","PR":"2","TR":1440},
                         {"country":"AUSTRIA","month":"MAR","SR":"Brad P","AC":"24","PR":"12","TR":700},
                         {"country":"ITALY","month":"MAR","SR":"Gim P","AC":"51","PR":"5","TR":200}
                    ];
            var tmpArray = [];
            var obj =[];
            for(var k=0; k<actual.length; k++){

                var position = tmpArray.indexOf(actual[k].month);
                if(position == -1){
                    tmpArray.push(actual[k].month);
                    val = {};
                    for(var i=0; i<actual.length; i++){
                        if(actual[i].month == actual[k].month){
                            val[actual[i].country] = actual[i]["AC"];
                        }
                    }
                    obj.push({month: actual[k].month, val:val});
                }


            }
```